# Select rows with unique value in a column, ordered by Timestamp?

Tags: sql, t-sql, group-by, distinct

I need to select 3 most recent unique rows by RelationShipId (So there is no duplicates of this) with the one that has a TimeStamp closest to today chosen.

I have a Query that looks like this now, but it doesn't work.

I get an: is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Script I have so far:

```
SELECT * FROM PlayerAction
WHERE [ActionType] = 'SomeString' AND [RelationShipType] = 'SomeString' AND [PlayerId] = 5 AND [Deleted] = 0
GROUP BY RelationShipId
ORDER BY [TimeStamp] DESC
OFFSET 1 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 3 ROWS ONLY
```

SampleData

```
{
 PlayerId=5
 ActionType="SomeString"
 RelationShipType="SomeString"
 RelationShipId=1
 TimeStamp=2019-07-04 07:45:47.400
 Deleted=0
}
{
 PlayerId=5
 ActionType="SomeString"
 RelationShipType="SomeString"
 RelationShipId=2
 TimeStamp=2019-07-03 14:29:10.530
 Deleted=0
}
{
 PlayerId=5
 ActionType="SomeString"
 RelationShipType="SomeString"
 RelationShipId=3
 TimeStamp=2019-07-03 13:56:26.057
 Deleted=0
}
```

imagine that there is like 5 rows with same RelationShipId, endless amount of RelationShipIds. I want the first 3 unique rows by TimeStamp, The three last PlayerActions made

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems you need distinct and top

```
SELECT distinct top 3 * FROM PlayerAction
        WHERE [ActionType] = 'SomeString' AND [RelationShipType] = 'SomeString' AND [PlayerId] = SomeNumber AND [Deleted] = 0
       ORDER BY [TimeStamp] DESC
```

Comment: I get 7 results from this and they are not distinct, have i missed something? :P

Comment: @Charlie sample data and expected output is helpfull to understand the problem so can you plesase add those in your question

Comment: Wow thanks bro, this worked perfectly it seems. Not alot of code either!